# Automatic Docstring Generator Plugin for Python Language in Neovim Code Editor

Tags: python, plugins, neovim, docstring

I am looking for a Neovim plugin that would be able to generate the initial template of docstring for a function based on the defined arguments and returns of this function. An example of what I want is illustrated below:

[image]

So, I wonder whether such a plugin exists. Or if it does not exist, how can I do this in Neovim for Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently giving https://github.com/heavenshell/vim-pydocstring a try. It doesn't seem to do much for classes, but it works fine for functions/methods!